# Регулярное выражение для выбора текста ссылки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
<h2><a href="http://asdf-fsd.com/asdf/detail/fsasfsda/">Текст ссылки заголовка</a></h2>
```

Нужно выбрать текст ссылки-заголовка.
Накидал тут:

```
(?<=<h2><a href=")(.*?)(?=</a></h2>)
```

Но это выбирает ещё и ссылку, а мне нужно сделать так (выдаёт ошибку):

```
(?<=<h2><a href=".*">)(.*?)(?=</a></h2>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, это работает

```
include_once('phpQuery-onefile.php');
$html = file_get_contents('http://demo.phpost.net/posts/arte/57/qsdfgh.html');
phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html, $charset = 'utf-8');

$result = array();
$result['title'] = pq('div.post-title')->find('h1')->text();

$result['img'] = array();
foreach (pq('div.post-contenido')->find('img') as $img) {
        $result['img'][] = pq($img)->attr('src');
}

$result['tags'] = array();
foreach (pq('div.tags-block')->find('a[rel=tag]') as $a) {
        $result['tags'][] = pq($a)->text();
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Кстати, в phpQuery-onefile.php я нашёл синтаксические ошибки, и пару переменных названных с ошибками. PhpStorm вам подсветит, если что.)

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста, используйте HTML парсеры. Использовать регулярки для парсинга HTML - дурной тон. Вот хороший: **`simple_html_dom`**. Там будете добираться до элементов с помощью CSS селекторов. :)

```
/* Или file_get_html('http://link/'); */
$html = str_get_html('<h2><a href="http://asdf-fsd.com/asdf/detail/fsasfsda/">Текст  ссылки заголовка</a></h2>');
$html->find('h2 > a',0)->innertext // текст
$html->find('h2 > a',0)->href // ссылка
```

Comment: Какой сайт Вы парсите? Скорее всего у вас отключен allow_url_fopen.

Comment: Посмотрите в файле simple_html_dom.php константу MAX_FILE_SIZE. Увеличьте. У меня работает с Вашей ссылкой. Дело в настройках парсера, либо сервере.

Comment: Смотрите, отличия между  file_get_html и str_get_html в основном только то, что первый текст достаёт из ссылки с помощью стандартной функции file_get_contents, а второй из аргумента. Для чистоты эксперемента возьмите так: $html = str_get_html(file_get_contents('LINK')). И станет ясно что что-то не так со стандартной функцией, почему-то она не рабоатет так как надо. Поэтому можете посмотерть что происходит, $test = file_get_contents('LINK'); var_dump($test);

Comment: Вот неправильно вам выдаёт file_get_contents, он должен строку выдавать string(65061), а говорите, претензий нет к нему. Говорю же, в нём дело.

Comment: да это я на ночь глядя уже туплю(перепечатывал), он выдаёт string

Answer (score 0):

```
$str='<\h2><\a href="http://asdf-fsd.com/asdf/detail/fsasfsda/">Текст ссылки заголовка<\/a><\/h2>'; ///
preg_match_all('|">(.*?)<\/a>|is', $str, $new_str); ///
```

`echo $new_str[1][0]` - необходимая строка.

Comment: Ваша регулярка выдаст мне все ссылки без разбора.  
Мне нужно, чтобы прослеживалась иерархия h2>a>text.